# Гарантирует ли указанная функция (алгоритм) уникальность строки (числа) при вызове в любое время?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt

Собственно функция:

```
QString Util::uniqueStringMs36()
{
    static qint64 uniqueVoucher = 0;//to guarantee the uniqueness if the same
    qint64 ms = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    static qint64 prevMs = 0;

    if (ms > prevMs) {
        uniqueVoucher = 0;
    }

    ms += uniqueVoucher;
    prevMs = ms;
    uniqueVoucher++;

    return QString::number(ms, 36); //base 36
}
```

Хотя написанна на `QT`, можно легко представить и в `std`, главный вопрос будет ли работать алгоритм - считываем миллисекуны от эпохи юникс, докладываем значение специальной инкриментируемой переменной (если функция будет вызванна в той же самой миллисекунде)

Comment: Я бы просто держал в статической переменной последнее сгенерированное значение, и в случае совпадения со вновь сгенерированным просто прибавлял 1, не мучаясь с этими нулями - не нулями. И переменных нужно меньше :)

Comment: @Harry а после рестарта программы как же? В файле хранить? А если на том же устройстве заменят диск с обнуленным значением, тогда заново пойдет

Comment: А ваше решение страдает абсолютно тем же недостатком :) И потом - вы считаете, что рестарт программы начнется через миллисекунду? А если это реально критично - то да, хранить в файле, потому что ваше-то решение тоже энергонезависимым не является...

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html#details

Comment: зачем вообще привязка ко времени? инкрементируйте счетчик каждый вызов, закройте мьютексом, состояние можно легко сохранять / загружать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы просто держал в статической переменной последнее сгенерированное значение, и в случае совпадения со вновь сгенерированным просто прибавлял 1, не мучаясь с этими нулями - не нулями. И переменных нужно меньше :)

```
QString Util::uniqueStringMs36()
{
    static qint64 last = 0;
    qint64 ms = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();

    if (ms <= last) ms = last+1;
    last = ms;

    return QString::number(ms, 36);
}
```

P.S. В свое время такой способ предлагался в FidoNet для генерации  идентификатора сообщений; не помню уж, вошел в FTS или нет...

Comment: Нужно, чтобы после перезагрузки программы и после смены диска уникальность сохранялась

Comment: Вы всерьез считаете, что мое решение хуже вашего в этом отношении? :) Я просто ваше же решение оптимизировал - ограничился одной переменной вместо ваших двух... И еще - давайте оценим - пусть смена диска и перезапуск займут... Ну, минуту. Вы в самом деле нагенерируете за одну миллисекунду 60000 строк? Только в этом случае у вас может быть сбой :)

Comment: сори, недопонял с первого раза. Но вопрос не снимается - будет ли алгоритм гарантировать уникальность?

Comment: В рамках указанного ограничения (те 60000 :)) и при том, что он не будет вызываться одновременно параллельно другой программой - таки да. Но представьте, что точно такая же программа работает на соседней машине (раз уж вы хотите даже винт менять беспроблемно) - тогда они обе могут и сгенерировать что-то одинаковое. Или две программы параллельно крутятся на одной машине. Или многопоточная программа... ну, эта пролетит уже на том, что обращение к статической переменной не атомарное. Вопрос всегда один - какая вероятность совпадения вас устраивает? Меньше какой величины?

Comment: убедили, устраивает в моих условиях ;)

Comment: Этот подход не работает. Если время будет одинаковым три раза подряд, то значение будет повторяться. А если сравнивать `lf(ms <= last)`, то получится практически инкрементный счетчик.

Comment: @VTT Да, согласен, профукал - `if (ms <= last) ms = last+1`. Исправил. Так нормально?